# Having trouble pulling information from an array within a function to print a histogram (C++)

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to print a histogram based off of values put into an array. I feel like I'm close, but I'm having trouble pulling the information from the array stored inside the histogram function that creates the histogram array (bin).

Standard Deviation is also computed, but that's not what I'm having issues with. Thank you for your time.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double mean(int size, int* numbers); 
double sDeviation(int numOfScores, int average, int* scores);
int* histogram(int numOfScores, int* scores);//<<Here is the call to the histogram function

int main()
{
int count = 0;
int scores[100];

while (true)
{
    int scoreToBeEntered;
    cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 109: ";
    cin >> scoreToBeEntered;

    if(scoreToBeEntered < 0)
        cout << "No value entered" << endl;
    else if(scoreToBeEntered != -1)
        scores[count++] = scoreToBeEntered;
    else
        break;
}

for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)//Here is where the issue starts
{   
    cout << i << "|" << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < bin[i]; k++) 
    {
        cout << '*'; 
    }
    cout << endl;//<< This is the chunk of code where I think the issue is. 
}

cout << "SD: " << sDeviation(count, mean(count, scores), scores) << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

int* histogram(int numOfScores, int* scores)
{
int* bin = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
    if(scores[i] >= 90)
    {
        bin[9]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] < 90)
    {
        bin[8]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 70 && scores[i] < 80)
    {
        bin[7]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 60 && scores[i] < 70)
    {
        bin[6]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 50 && scores[i] < 60)
    {
        bin[5]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 40 && scores[i] < 50)
    {
        bin[4]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 30 && scores[i] < 40)
    {
        bin[3]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 20 && scores[i] < 30)
    {
        bin[2]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 10 && scores[i] < 20)
    {
        bin[1]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 0 && scores[i] < 10)
    {
        bin[0]++;
    }

    return bin; 

}   


double sDeviation(int numOfScores, int average, int* scores)
{
double deviation = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
    deviation += pow(scores[i] - average, 2);

return sqrt(deviation / numOfScores);
}

double mean(int size, int* numbers)
{
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    sum += numbers[i];

return sum / size;
}
```

This is the output my code should produce afterwards.

Case 1: 100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 40, 20, and 5.

9| ***
 8| **
 7| **
 6| **
 5|
 4| *
 3|
 2| *
 1|
 0| *

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have not made your question very well for receiving an answer. Your question must show the reproducible problem. Here the reprudicble problem is your whole program. Unfortunately StackOverflow is not a site of "please debug my code for me" :-).  At least reduce your code to the function that returns a result you don't understand: you will get much more answers this way.

Comment: The implicit StackOverflow "rule" that's not written could maybe be said this way : show us your efforts trying to understant the issue, and we'll tell you the mistakes we see/we know. Here you have maybe thrown a bit too much of code at once, without trying to catch the code that is faulty. A good step would be to go in the Visual Studio debuger to try to find a function that behaves not accroding to your expectation. And then focus your question on this function.

Comment: IIRC, in Visual-Studio: Alt-F8 to put a breakpoint. Alt-F5 to launch the program so as to reach the breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to think of a better way to submit the question.

Comment: You never actually call `histogram`.

Comment: How would I go about that? I'm trying to read as much as I can about calling functions using pointers but I'm pretty much stuck.